# Is God really Merciful according to the Bible?

Tags: exegesis, nature-of-god, old-testament, 1-samuel

1st Samuel 15, Saul disobeys God but the Bible says that God is Merciful also He commanded that "Thou shall not kill". Why did He ask Saul to kill all the Amalekite people without sparing their livestock too. I mean that really sounds Wicked to me asides it contradicting the commandment. How is God Merciful? If He's sending Israel to kill her enemies when Jesus commands we love and pray for our enemies or for not stopping Jephtah from sacrificing his daughter(a ram was provided in the case of Isaac). How is this bloodbath Mercy or rather How is He still a Merciful God?

> **P.S.** An in depth answer would be appreciated

Comment: It would probably be helpful to make clear the exact question that you want answered. I attempted an answer below, but you did ask 4 distinct questions.

Comment: There are really good ways of understanding the OT “terror passages” explained by Church Fathers like Origen. Maybe you could look into those interpretations.

Comment: Alex It's just one question

Comment: "Is God really merciful according to the Bible?" (God's character in Scripture) "Why did He ask Saul to kill...?" (God's motive for a single action) "How is God merciful? (God's character in general, maybe examples of His actions), "How is this bloodbath mercy?" (How 1 event aligns with God's character). And now you added a summary thay I think is how to mesh these questions together, How is God still merciful according to the Bible in light of the command to kill everything in 1 Samuel 15?

Comment: The other questions within the main are just to buttress/support the initial. e.g. If he is Merciful then "Why did He ask Saul..."

Answer (score 5):

1. It is really more like "Thou shalt not *murder*" rather than just kill.
2. According to a correct formulation of [divine command theory](https://www.iep.utm.edu/divine-c/), which is grounded in [God's nature as the ultimate source of good](https://www.reasonablefaith.org/media/reasonable-faith-podcast/the-euthyphro-dilemma-once-again/), what God commands people to do is always good. It may or may not be obvious to us why, but typically makes sense upon 1) further study or 2) looking back at the big picture.
3. The big picture is that in the Old Testament, **Israelite military victory and conquest ultimately 1) brings glory to God and 2) brings people to salvation.** This is because as God's chosen people, God continuously command them ways in which they would be **set apart**, hence many of the rules in Old Testament, even [wearing strands of different types of clothing](https://www.gotquestions.org/divine-command-theory.html) (Deut. 22:11). That way the nations may know that Israel is unique because they serve Yahweh. God's desire is that all nations would know Him, not just Israel (Isaiah 42:6, 49:6), so anything that makes the nations realize that Yahweh is the true God would be a good thing, such as God demonstrating His power to the prophets of Baal in 1 Kings 18. Unstoppable military victories many times helped nations realize that Israel's God is the real God. It is a demonstration of God's power.
4. **This action of God (the "bloodbath") is just**. **It is people getting what they deserve**. We all deserve the same thing that they received. I would say that not *every* action of God is merciful because I think it is not possible for any single action of God to be both merciful and just. However, **this "bloodbath" is most certainly just.** In fact, if God was not merciful and was only just, **we all would be dead and already in hell forever** (Romans 3:23, Romans 6:23, James 2:10). That is what justice is. People getting what they deserve. **We all deserve death because we have so often violated the moral law of a holy God.** The fact that you are still breathing is a sign of God's mercy.
5. God doesn't enjoy killing people (Ezekiel 18:23, 32). He truly desires that people will repent and be saved (Ezekiel 18:21). He often gives them ample opportunity for this, though they are rarely take it.
6. **The pattern in the Old Testament is Rebel-Repent-Redeem**. Over and over again. God is slow to anger (Exodus 34:6, Psalm 103:8), and he is indeed very merciful (2 Samuel 24:14, 2 Corinthians 1:3). He, many times, waits generations to carry out judgment on a people (including Israel) even though they are filled with sin and wickedness. He also relents when people repent (Jonah and Ninevah). He wouldn't destroy peoples if there were good people in them (recall Sodom and Gomorrah?).

I think the reason so many people have questions like this is people forgetting

1) what it means for God to be just

2) what it means for God to be holy

3) the big picture of how God set Israel apart with his laws and how it lead to other nations realizing that Yahweh was the One True God.

We can trust that what God does is good because He is essentially good (Luke 18:19, Psalm 34:8, 100:5, 106:1, 107:1, 119:68, etc.). It is one of His essential attributes, which means that there is no possible world in which God exists but is not good. So, wow, do we have a good God!

Comment: I can't find the right Bible verse now, but somewhere in the old testament, possibly in Joshua, God says something like "the reason I am making you victorious over your enemies is not because I love you more than them, it is because I hate them more than you". But, that was in old testament times, we are living in new testament times now.

Comment: I can't speak on an uncited verse, but we can know God's character doesn't change from the Old to the New Testament, or He wouldn't be immutable. That includes the mention of God hating the wicked in Psalm 5:5, 11:5, others, and Leviticus  20:23  that looks most similar to what you mentioned. This hatred also stems from God's holiness & desire for justice. That doesn't mean that God doesn't still love them and demonstrate that by sending His son in the midst of our wickedness (Romans 5:8). Jesus demonstrates a similar disdain for wickedness w/ the cleansing of the temple, Matt. 7:21-23, etc.

Comment: So basically in the short run God is Just and in the long run he is Merciful.

Comment: References Ex 32:7-14; Deu 9:4-6.

Comment: Ehh not really. Just and merciful are two of his attributes and some actions of His correspond to either of these on a regular basis. People in hell will always be examples of his justice and people in heaven would always be examples of his mercy. At any given time on earth, God is exhibiting both characteristics with various actions of His, as the sustainer of all the earth and as he works everything in conformity with His will. His good, pleasing, and perfect will (Romans 12:2). God's discipline of us would be His justice at work & His continuing to give us breath would be His mercy at work

Comment: @Constantthin so in Exodus 32 we see God wants consume them with His wrath "in order that I may make a great nation of you" and in Deuteronomy 9 we see God is driving out the nations "not because of your rigteousness...but because of the wickedness of these nations...and that he may confirm the word that the LORD swore to your fathers..." So twice mentioned to fulfill God's promise of Israel being a great nation, and once mentioned because of their wickedness. Makes sense. Nothing specifically mentioned about hatred here that i see but sounds good!

Comment: Hmmmm... so If God's justice also involves killing whenever required so basically the Christian belief on the Devil being evil or as the opposer would be that If God were evil (hypothetically speaking) then the Devil would have chosen the exact opposite(good). Also this means morally and spiritually what's good according to Christianity is whatever the Creator decides or does... is this correct?

Comment: God's justice would involve killing "whenever just" because "whenever required" doesn't hold any meaning.  God is the greatest conceivable being, which entails moral perfection. See my answer's mention about God's essential goodness, Plantiga's "The Nature of Necessity," WLC's discussions on the ontological and moral arguments, and "The Essential Moral Perfection of God" by Laura L. Garcia. This means it is metaphysically impossible for God to be evil. The devil is not just defined as the opposite of God, but the father of lies (John 8:44), evil one (Matt. 13:19), the tempter (Matt. 4:3), etc.

Comment: And yes: what is good is what the Creator does because He is good! His nature is the ultimate standard of good. His commands stem from His nature, and thus can accurately be described by the same words that we describe His nature i.e. just, merciful, gracious, loving, etc. This is why the Euthyphro dilemma is a false dilemma.

Comment: @Alex Strasser. The word "stiff-necked" is used both in Ex 32 and in Deu 9. God uses this word to describe the Israelites. He calls the Canaanites "wicked" and the Israelites he calls "stiff-necked". To be wicked is worse than to be stiff-necked, apparently. God hates both, but hates wickedness more than stiff-neckedness. Acts 7:51 also mention "stiff-neckedness".

Comment: It makes sense that wicked is stronger than stiff-necked, but I'm not sure why or how we know if God hates one more than the other. If we break one commandment, we break them all (James 2:10). Israel is also called wicked in Numbers 14:27, 35, Isaiah 9:17, and Jeremiah 13:10. Isaiah actually says that everyone is wicked in 9:17.

Comment: @Alex Strasser. You are right in that the Israelites also were labeled "wicked", but doesn't Deu 9:4-6, imply that the Canaanites were more wicked than the Israelites, and that that was one of the reasons why the Israelites were going to replace them? And when Isaiah says that everybody is wicked does that include himself? Furthermore, 1 John 5:16 implies that there are different degrees of sins, some leads to death, others don't. For instance, Jesus clearly showed that to not keeping the Sabbath holy one week is a very small and insignificant sin.

Comment: @Constantthin. Possibly...but not necessarily, it doesn't seem. But yes that seems a possibility. I imagine that yes, Isaiah includes himself when he says that everyone is wicked.  I'm not sure "insignificant" is a good word for any sin. In the Old Testament, violating the Sabbath incurred the death penalty, and Jesus just showed that the Jewish tradition adding on rules that weren't present was wrong. I haven't confirmed definitively that Jesus or his disciples actually violated the Sabbath as given in the OT.

Comment: @Constantthin Any "small" sin deserves damnation because that is imperfection when compared to a holy and perfect God. 1 John 5:16 does mention two types of sin, but doesn't imply that something like lying doesn't lead to death but, for example, killing does.  It seems to be along the lines of the unforgivable sin/blasphemy of the Spirit aka unbelief/not true repentance as in not saving faith. By death, it's referring to eternal death, and there is no single sin like "lying" or "murder" that leads to eternal damnation.

Answer (score 3):

1) **Knowledge**. In times when God reveals himself more clearly through his actions, people are held responsible for that knowledge. God had been displaying his wonders through his acts of kindness toward Israel, therefore the peoples who lived closest to Israel were held responsible with more severe acts of judgement. Egypt was one example, with an escalating series of miracles making clear the extent of the Egyptian people's rebellion against God. In 1 Samuel 15, the Kenites are warned to not assist the Amalekites or be included in his judgment against the Amalekites. They are also commended for assisting the Israelites in the past, whereas the Amalekites had always been hostile.

2) **Patience**. The Amalekites oppressed Israel for centuries, yet God held back, giving them a chance to change. As a more extreme example of God's patience, consider the people who lived during the time of Noah and were wiped out by the flood. They were warned well in advance, but refused to change. Methusaleh's name means "When he dies, it will come." His name is a prophecy of the coming wrath. If God were long on justice and short on mercy, he would have made Methusaleh live a short life. If long on mercy, he would bless Methusaleh with a long life. Which did God arrange? Methusaleh lived 969 years, longer than any other human in all of history. God chose mercy - with a limit.

3) **Unselfishness**. When executing God's decrees, Israel was not to profit. They were doing this for God, not for themselves. That is why the animals had to be slaughtered. If they took the animals, they would face a moral hazard - profiting personally from the eradication of other peoples. There was a battle fought by Joshua that they lost because an Israelite took some treasures as plunder when they were commanded not to take plunder.

4) **Impartiality**. When the people doubted God's goodness in the time of Moses in the story of the twelve spies, he permitted the Amalekites to defeat them in battle. In that case, the Amalekites were instruments of God's judgment against Israel. This shows that since God favored the Amalekites when they obeyed him, he had set an example for them to follow, that if they obeyed Israel's God, they could expect favor and mercy; He is a God for all people, not just one nation. God did the same for Egypt, sparing them from famine through Joseph, but they later repayed grace with slavery and infanticide. God also prospered Babylon and other empires, only to overturn them when they refused to turn from evil.